# Combine output of two grep results without spaces in between

Tags: bash

I have a file:

```
...
version=1
...
subversion=2
..
```

I wish to display "version.subversion", so in current case "1.2".

What I currently have looks like this:

```
echo `echo -n $(grep "version=" file | awk -F= '{print $2 "."}'); grep -n "subversion=" file | awk -F= '{print $2}'`
```

So I have two separate greps following each other and the first one is wrapped into `echo -n` to get rid of the space that I would otherwise have between them.

This works, but doesn't look ideal. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's simplify it one step at a time.

1. The outer `` echo `...` `` can go. Backticks and echo are basically inverse operations and they (more or less) cancel out when combined.

   ```
   echo -n "$(grep "version=" file | awk -F= '{print $2 "."}')"
   grep -n "subversion=" file | awk -F= '{print $2}'
   ```
2. An easier way to combine the two lines is to embed them inside a single printout.

   ```
   echo "$(grep "version=" file | awk -F= '{print $2}').$(grep "subversion=" file | awk -F= '{print $2}')"
   ```
3. Awk can both search and print. No need for grep.

   ```
   echo "$(awk -F= '$1=="version" {print $2}' file).$(awk -F= '$1=="subversion" {print $2}' file)"
   ```
4. You could make this easier to read by using `printf` to split it across multiple lines:

   ```
   printf '%s.%s\n' \
       "$(awk -F= '$1=="version" {print $2}' file)" \
       "$(awk -F= '$1=="subversion" {print $2}' file)"
   ```

That looks pretty good. But you know what? This screams for a one-pass solution. Awk is a pretty capable mini-language in its own right. We could have it save all the key/value pairs into a map and then print the results at the end:

```
awk -F= '{map[$1]=$2} END {print map["version"] "." map["subversion"]}' file
```

Here `{map[$1]=$2}` is executed for each line of the input file, saving the keys and values to a map. When the file is finished the `END` block runs and prints the two desired fields with a `.` in between.

Answer (score 4):

If you know for sure that the `version` line comes first, you can do something like this:

```sh
$ grep -E '^(sub)?version=' infile | cut -d= -f2 | paste -sd.
1.2
```

which works as follows:

```sh
grep -E '^(sub)?version=' infile | # Get lines starting with "version"/"subversion"
    cut -d= -f2 |                  # Print part after "="
    paste -sd.                     # Join lines, separated by "."
```

---

And if the order is not deterministic, we can add a (reverse) sort step:

```sh
grep -E '^(sub)?version=' infile | sort -r | cut -d= -f2 | paste -sd.
```

Comment: In this context it probably doesn't matter that it spawns 3 procs. Nice.

Answer (score 1):

One `awk` solution:

```
$ awk -F"=" '/^version/ {v=$2;next} /^subversion/ {sv=$2} END {printf "%s.%s\n",v,sv}' file
1.2
```

Where:

- `-F"="` - input field separator
- `/^*version/` - search patterns
- `v/sv=$2` - store the 2nd field
- `next` - optional; skips to next input line
- `END/printf` - output the results as `v.sv`

Answer (score 1):

Lol, so I wrote this awk and then noticed that almost every feature was in another answer (++) except quick exit once done and if `version` or `subversion` is missing, `0` is printed instead (ie. `1.0` or `0.2`):

```
$ awk -F\= '                             # set field delimiter to =
$1~/^(sub)?version$/ {                   # only process sub- or version fields 
    a[$1]=$2                             # hash key and value
    if(a["version"] && a["subversion"])  # once both met
        exit                             # no more need to process so exit
}
END {                                    # in end or after exit
    print ((v=a["version"])?v:0) "." ((v=a["subversion"])?v:0)  # output value or 0
}' file
```

Output:

```
1.2
```

or:

```
1.0  # if missing subversion
```

or:

```
0.2  # if missing version
```

Answer (score 0):

I also used `awk` for a one-pass, one-proc solution. I `quit` after `subversion` to avoid wasted I/O and cycles, though this is likely a small enough task that it doesn't matter - just like to stay in the habit of being as efficient as possible in case the paradigm changes a little sometime in the future.

```
 awk -F= '/^version/{v=$2}; /^subversion/{ printf "%d.%d\n",v,$2; quit; }' file
```

Comment: This *does* still assume they will be in order. The other similar solutions allow either order, and still work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases `source` can do the job, for this test file:

```
$ cat file.txt 
ls
some text
version=1
subversion=2
echo ok

$ ver=$(. file.txt &> /dev/null; echo "${version:-0}.${subversion:-0}")
$ echo $ver
1.2
```

Sourcing done in subshell so it won't change current env. All output and errors thrown to `/dev/null` and echoed only needed info.

Comment: If there's `rm -f file.txt` file `file.txt` will be lost and other possibilities.